# Add paragraphs item to user entity

Tags: 7, users, paragraphs

I want to create a new paragraph item to a user bundle. This is the code:

```
$name = "Test";
$userdata = user_load($user->uid);
$paragraph = entity_create('paragraphs_item', array('field_name' => 'field_userdata', 'bundle' => 'userdata'));
$paragraph->setHostEntity('user', $userdata);
$paragraph->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $name;
$paragraph->save();
```

But nothing happens, no errors, no new entity.. 
Are there differences to adding to a node bundle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure following things are configured properly:

1. Is [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module is enabled in your site?
2. Have you enabled `Logging and errors` from `admin/config/development/logging` page, to see site errors?
3. In second line you have not defined `$user` object, are you defined else where?
4. How are you calling this function?

If everything is configured properly then execute following code:

```
$name = "Test";
global $user;
$userdata = user_load($user->uid);
$paragraph = entity_create('paragraphs_item', array('field_name' => 'field_userdata'));
$paragraph->setHostEntity('user', $userdata);
$paragraph->field_name[$userdata->language][]['value'] = $name;
$entity->save();
```